# File in local storage on Java, Android

Tags: java, android

I serialization object into new file in local storage by this mean:

```
ObjectOutputStream output=new ObjectOutputStream(openFileOutput("settings.dat", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
output.writeObject(this);
output.close();
```

But in another function I must check file for exist:

```
File file=new File("settings.dat");
if (file.exists()) Toast.makeText(this, "yes", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

file.exists() returne false always. Help me please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
File file = new File(getFilesDir() + "/settings.dat");
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir%28%29